# Is there an Emacs read-only or view mode that allows inserting some text?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, bookmarks

Here's the use case: I'm writing a novel in Emacs (in org-mode). One part of my writing/editing flow is to read over some large portion of what I've written, collecting notes/possible edits/etc as I go. The sort of thing you'd do, on paper, by printing it all out and then writing notes in the margin.

I want to prevent myself from, as I do this kind of review, actually doing **any** writing -- but that's surprisingly hard. Like, if the buffer is editable, I start to type a brief note about a fix, then find myself starting to restructure / fix a sentence, and next thing I know, I've spent five minute polishing 
a single paragraph. This not only slows me down, it breaks my ability to imagine a reader's response.

I've tried just putting the buffer in view-mode, and that sort of works -- but then it's laborious to try to identify the places I want to go back and review/fix up.

My ideal would be, to have something in view-mode, which I genuinely can't edit, but which, as I move the cursor through it, I could hit some key combination, and it would allow me to enter a brief note in the minibuffer, which would then get inserted into the main buffer, at point, possibly inside brackets or a comment or some such.

Does anyone know of something like that? Or have any pointers to something similar which I could try to adapt?

Comment: Pressing `C-x C-q` toggles the Read only mode.

Comment: HI Dan. It seems to me that you'll get better answers if you ask in the Writing Stack Exchange. I searched for emacs and found answers like this one: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/4549/emacs-for-creative-writing

Comment: this package, [org-noter](https://github.com/weirdNox/org-noter) looks promising

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily set bookmarks at any locations. And bookmarks can contain annotations.

If you use library [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus):

- The annotations are in Org Mode by default, and they can even be separate files (by default they are part of the bookmarks themselves, so stored in your bookmarks file).
- You can bookmark not just a position but also [a region](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkedRegion) of text, whether a sentence, paragraph, page, or an arbitrary span of text.
- You can [automatically name](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutonamedBookmarks) bookmarks as you set them, if you don't care about the names.

---

**Updated after OP's comment** saying *"I prefer to shove the comments/questions/notes directly into the text of the novel. Because I end up adding/deleting/moving text a ton, and I want the notes to move with the text"*:

*Bookmarks move with the surrounding text.* That is, they generally get *relocated automatically*, since the surrounding text is recorded as part of the bookmark, and when jumping to a bookmark that text is looked for.
Occasionally the context has changed so much that a bookmark can't be relocated automatically, and you are prompted to relocate it manually.

But yes, bookmarks are stored in a bookmark file, separately from the files they target. There are both advantages and disadvantages to this feature. Advantages include (1) removing clutter from the text (annotations, including notes about possible text changes are metadata), (2) immediate access to particular text locations from anywhere, (3) a separate, persistent record/history of work or thoughts on it, (4) you can have multiple, separate sets of bookmarks/annotations for the same target text.

One thing you might find handy, when using bookmarks especially for annotating a particular file: **`C-x p C-l`** switches to a bookmark file that has *only bookmarks for the current file or buffer*, creating such a file on the fly if none
exists. (This is available only with [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus).)

Comment: This is a very interesting idea, I will likely try it out (since it gives me some of what I want, out of the box). That said, I... think I somewhat strongly prefer to shove the comments/questions/notes directly into the text of the novel. Because I end up adding/deleting/moving text a ton, and I want the notes to move with the text.

Comment: Updated, to speak to your comment.